# .NET Web Api same http verb, different name method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

There seem to be a lot of questions answered where the http verb, the method name or its signature differ. But none answers what I am trying to achieve.

On a controller I would like to have two methods called Get1(decimal) and Get2(decimal). Both should be addressable by the caller via an appropriate URL.

Background is, one method considers some standard values, the other one doesn't.

I don't know how to implement that. Do I have to modify the routing? Do I have to use ActionNameAttribute?

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: For a very simple version of something the same, I was able to do this just by using `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("TheAPI", "api/{controller}/{action}");`

Comment: Have you actually tried putting those two methods in your controller? Web API will allow you to have multiple methods that use the same verb so long as the name differs (i.e. route).

Comment: What did you try and why doesn't it work?

Comment: as @stuartd said, you can setup a new route for your application to use the action name, but it is not very common in web api. It is more common to use the **Route** attribute on your actions

Comment: I couldn't quite figure out what kind of route I would have to add. As soon as I do, I'll report back here.